# Closest to in active record

Tags: rails-activerecord

We have a model called "games" with the following attributes: id, contest_id:integer, high:integer
We need to get a list of games with the high closest to say 500 for each contest_id?
Can this be done only using ActiveRecord?

Note: The “high” value can be higher or lower than 500 (as long as it's the closest), and one game per contest_id.

Comment: please add more details

Comment: The “high” value can be higher or lower than 500 (as long as it's the closest), and one game per contest_id.

Comment: so you want greater than 500 or lower than 500 values for high, right??

Comment: but what should be the range??

Comment: No range, just the closest to 500